# Django 1.4 Development Environment with zc.buildout

Tags: django, buildout

I am trying to create a dev environment for the Django 1.4 project using the following guide:

http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/a-django-development-environment-with-zc-buildout

**virtualenv** part of the guide runs ok with the following output:

```
virtualenv project
New python executable in project\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools................done.
Installing pip...................done.
```

After that I am able to activate dev environment. Now I create directory named **Source**, download the **bootstrap.py** to it and create a **buildout.cfg** with the following content:

```
[buildout]
parts =
```

And run bootstrap.py for the following result:

```
Creating directory 'C:\\Dropbox\\XYZ\\project\\Source\\bin'.            
Creating directory 'C:\\Dropbox\\XYZ\\project\\Source\\parts'.          
Creating directory 'C:\\Dropbox\\XYZ\\project\\Source\\eggs'.           
Creating directory 'C:\\Dropbox\\XYZ\\project\\Source\\develop-eggs'.   
Generated script 'C:\\Dropbox\\XYZ\\project\\Source\\bin\\buildout'.
```

Here comes the problem part - **Installing Django** I configure the buildout.cfg to the following and run bin\buildout created by bootstrap:

```
[buildout]
parts = django

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
version = 1.4
```

After running bin\buildout i get the following error:

```
(project) C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\Source>bin\buildout.exe                      
Traceback (most recent call last):           

File "C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\Source\bin\buildout-script.py", line 15, in <module>                                                                               import site # imports custom buildout-generated site.py                       

File "C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\Source\parts\buildout\site.py", line 601, in <module>                                                                              main()                                                                        

File "C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\Source\parts\buildout\site.py", line 584, in main                                                                                  known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)                                    

File "C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\Source\parts\buildout\site.py", line 328, in addsitepackages                                                                       import pkg_resources                                                        

ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Although if I run python directly in project environment I can import pkg_resources with no error:

```
(project) C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\Source>python                                
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32                                                                              Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.          
>>> import pkg_resources                                                        
>>> pkg_resources                                                               
<module 'pkg_resources' from 'C:\Dropbox\XYZ\project\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py'>
```

I am completely struck here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have the definitive answer, but here are some brainstorm thoughts:

- Why the virtualenv? Buildout itself provides isolation, so no virtualenv is needed. Could you re-try with just a bootstrap.py and your buildout.cfg? So just run bootstrap.py with your system python?
- Do you have buildout installed globally, perhaps? They can interfere.
- The latest 1.5.2 buildout has some problems with site.py files in some situations, which is a possible reason for it failing inside a virtualenv. Could you try the special 1.4.4 bootstrap mentioned in http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.5.2#system-python-and-zc-buildout-1-5 ?
- `bin/buildout -vvv` gives you much more debugging info.

An additional comment: the `version` setting in djangorecipe is deprecated in the latest versions of djangorecipe. You can remove it. If you want to pin Django you have to pin it in your buildout's `[version]` list.

Comment: Thank you a lot you made my day! The bootstrap v1.5.2 was the problem. Virtualenv is needed to isolate the buildout packages so team could work on different branches/modifications of project. But maybe I am getting something wrong - anyway I am still learning and will be my entire life.

Comment: Virtualenv should not provide more isolation than you're already getting with buildout. At least, I'm pretty sure about that. Buildout doesn't install anything globally. I use it all the time for different branches and projects, all of them have their own buildout. But... an extra virtualenv layer won't hurt :-)

Comment: buildout is installing setuptools globally, so virtualenv is needed!

Answer (score 3):

The guide you are following is a little bit obsolete. It will fail when processing the `[django]` part, specifically in the `version` variable. You must specify the versions in the new way, which is showed in the [djangorecipe page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe/1.1.2). This is:

```
[buildout]
parts = django
versions = versions

[versions]
django = 1.4
```

Comment: At some point, buildout seemed to stop respecting this django version, and just downloaded the latest one (1.5 for me just now). Capitalizing it to "Django = 1.4" seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Case should not matter according to this commit https://github.com/rvanlaar/djangorecipe/commit/64762ddbb56a4beaf061a615d49adbdaf018cd9a

Comment: That commit is newer than the 1.5 release of djangorecipe, which is the most recent one on PyPI as I write this.